# Azure File Access / Accessing custom configuration files in windows azure cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-storage, file-access

I have found a number of articles on stackoverflow which I have tried to use to answer a question I have about file access in a windows azure cloud service.

My application has a number of xml files which are used as custom configuration files and these are stored within the web project as this is the most convenient place to be able to manage/edit them.

Now when deploying this solution to a local IIs server I can obviously access and read these xml files easily. I had originally expected this would be exactly the same in a windows azure cloud service. But I found I was getting file access errors when just trying to read these files.

After reading a number of articles on here it is apparent that this is not the case, and to access file storage I have to configure local storage.

This however doesn't quite fit my scenario as this storage is temporary, not shared across role instances, and will not be populated with the xml configurations files on deployment.

I want to keep my configuration files within the project as they are tied to a particular release version so it is nice that these are all also under source control and nice because they are deployed with each deployment released.

I can think of one way of utilising the local storage which may be possible but not sure how. Would there be any way on deployment to copy all of the local configuration files to the local storage account and then the application can access them from local storage as and when required. The fact that this would be temporary and not shared would be ok I think as each instance would have its own local storage with the configuration files deployed too. But I would need to make sure if the cloud service crashed the local storage would be repopulated with the necessary configuration files

Or are there any other alternatives.?

Obviously in all the articles the suggestion is to use azure stoage and use blobs, and I could do this, but this presents extra problems and I have to find a way to deploy all the configuration files automatically with each deployment to azure.

any help on how this can be best be achieved would be gratefully received.

As I mentioned in one of the comments below, The configuration files are standard xml files, which are included as content within the solution. When deployed to an on premise server config files are published and deployed and can be read. But when deploying to azure cloud service, the config files are deployed (as I have checked by remoting on and finding the files on the cloud service vm). But whenever I try and read them (With an XmlSerializer) I get an access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

Kramer, if you are including the config files in the project, and either setting Copy to Output to Copy Always, or setting Build Type to Content, then accessing the config files should work just like it does in IIS.  Check out the following 2 posts for examples of how to do this:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/01/28/adding-files-to-your-windows-azure-service-package.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2012/06/08/add-files-to-your-windows-azure-package-using-role-content-folders.aspx

Comment: The two links above are pretty much what I am trying to do. So the configuration files I already have in my solution are already marked as content and so do get included in the deployed package. I know this because they get included in a standard build to an on premise machine and everything works. I have also enabled remote access to the cloud service and had a look at the deployed application files and the config files do exist. Its just that when running as a cloud service I get the access denied error. Is there some security configuration I am missing, or something else I am missing?